# SELECT Users from WordPress based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: sql, wordpress, where-clause

I am trying to create a SQL WHERE query with multiple conditions based on input of a search form to find users. Each input is functioning when only one field is selected in the form. When a combination of two or more input fields is submitted, it does not give any result.

Please note that the two options here are just for illustration. I have a whole lot more options being used. So it's necessary to search each option individually.

Here's the code:

```
    global $wpdb;

        $user_ids = array();
        $user_query = null;

        if (isset($_REQUEST['search']) && !empty($_REQUEST['search']) ) {
            $s = $_REQUEST['search'];
            $user_query .= "((meta_key='first_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='last_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='display_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='nice_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
        }

        if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
            $s = $_REQUEST['email'];
            if ($user_query) {
            $user_query .= "AND (meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            } else {
            $user_query .= "(meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            }
        }


        if (!empty($user_query)) {
            $wp_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta JOIN $wpdb->users ON $wpdb->usermeta.user_id=$wpdb->users.ID WHERE ($user_query)");
        }
```

Here's the SQL query that should be executed:

```
$wp_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta JOIN $wpdb->users ON $wpdb->usermeta.user_id=$wpdb->users.ID WHERE (((meta_key='first_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='last_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='display_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='nice_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')) AND (meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$s."'))");
```

Please help me find the error in the above query.

Comment: I would run `echo $wpdb->last_query` to show the query being run then copy it and run it directly in PHPMyAdmin.  If it returns nothing, I'd simplify it until it returns something then find out what is causing it to return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try [WP_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query). Makes these kind of queries a lot easier. There's great documentation on it.